# Count the number of associated value in sails?

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

How can we limit the number of many-to-many associations in sails? There are two tables, books and person and the condition is that a person is allowed to have only five books. Trying to implement this logic inside the findOrCreate() in Books.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you want to limit number of books to prevent from adding new book to person, is this correct?

Then, how about to count books associated with a person in [beforeCreate](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) lifecycle callback?
You can count how many books person has and depending on the result continue operation (or not).

api/models/Books.js

```
beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {
  sails.models.person.find(...).populate('books').exec(...)
},
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to show an error to the user. So, it would be more useful if it was the logic is not in the lifecycle callback..